Railway Error when deploying DJango App due to botocore dependency (boto3)
After installing boto3 package to integrate with AWS S3 buckets, the application fails on deployment. The Railway error is "botocore 1.34.93 depends on urllib3<1.27 and >=1.25.4; python_version < "3.10". On the local server (127.0.0.1:8000) everything works fine, and app deployed with no issues before installing boto3.
Upon installing boto3, I expected the app to deploy on Railway as it did before installing the package. Any suggestions?

It probably means that you're using the latest version of urllib3 (which is a required dependency for botocore to work). You can try to download the required version with the following syntax :
pip install urllib3==<version>
And replace <version> by the version you need

Thanks. You were on the right track. The issue was related to the urllib3 version. I got the code to deploy by deleting the version requirement altogether.

I found a solution: in requirements.txt, I deleted the version requirement for urllib3 which allows Railway to find and install a version of urllib3 that is compatible with boto3 and botocore. By looking at the Railway deployment logs, Railway goes from latest version to newest version until it finds a compatible one.
Something odd about this error is that I never chose a version for urllib3. The version in requirements.txt was selected by the system when I installed boto3. It is odd that the version added to the requirements would be incompatible when deploying.
